# Multiple Prototype cells displaying in one row in tableview in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, tableview, prototype, cell

I'm having an issue with a tableview in xamarin.ios, I'm trying to use multiple prototype cells but all of the prototype cells are showing on the same row in the table view and I want them to have there own row, does anyone have the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing the prototypes? Could you update your original post with the printscreen of the Storyboard?

Comment: I made the cells in the storyboard and gave them data with a normal list and a get cell method- I tried posting a print screen but it says i have to be level 10 to do so.

Comment: can you share your GetCell() method code over here? Are you using externel XIB's ?

Comment: No external XIB, my code for the get cell is posted

Answer (score 0):

you will likely need to overide the rows in section method of your UITableView's Source class.

```
public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
     return (nint)MyTableDataList?.Count;
}
```

If you'd like to provide some actual code, we may be able to be more accurate.

Comment: public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
  {
   return messages.Count;
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is the GetCell message in the table source.

public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            //Incoming message

var cell =   (IncomingCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("IncomingCell", indexPath);

```
        var message = messages[indexPath.Row];

        cell.updateCel(message);
```

var cell1 =(OutGoingCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("OutgoingCell", indexPath);

```
        var message1 = messages[indexPath.Row];

        cell1.updatecell(message1);

        return cell;


    }
```